# Download file stored in google drive or one drive attached to email c#

Tags: c#, email, imap, onedrive

Need some help, i need to download a file stored in google drive or one drive, but the link to that file comes as an attachment from an email or at least thats what i can see, i have succesfully read the email using IMAP MimeKit but if i ask for attachments the result is false...

Anyone has some clue about this? I dont know if i make my self clear about this?

```
IList<MailKit.UniqueId> uids = inbox.Search(SearchQuery.And(SearchQuery.DeliveredOn(oDate),SearchQuery.SentOn(oDate)));
foreach (var message in inbox.Fetch(uids, MessageSummaryItems.UniqueId | MessageSummaryItems.BodyStructure | MessageSummaryItems.All))
{
    //DO SOMETHING...
    
    if (message.Body is BodyPartMultipart)
    {
        var multipart = (BodyPartMultipart)message.Body;
        var AttEmailParts = multipart.BodyParts.OfType<BodyPartBasic>().Where(x => x.IsAttachment);
        if (AttEmailParts.Count() > 0)
        {
            // Download Attachment/Files
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: It's either a link somewhere inside the email, or it's an attachment. If you're saying the file is stored in Drive, for example, then it must be a link rather than an attachment. (Some mail clients may be programmed to detect such links and give them the visual appearance of an attachment but that doesn't mean that an attachment actually exists when you examine the raw email)

Comment: This isn't enough to reproduce the problem or comment usefully.

Comment: The case is this, someone send and email, that i read using imap, and that email has a link (i asume) to a google drive file. Can i download this file looking for the link in that email ?